# reprojecting and resampling rasters

Tags: pyqgis

This python script for qgis should reproject all the raster files in a folder and resample it to 10 m. Raster file type should be Float32. The script doesn't produce any result.

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import *

inputDir = "R:\\LAI_Biom_Maps\\kriging_Gladys\\in"

outputDir = "R:\\LAI_Biom_Maps\\kriging_Gladys\\out"


for i in os.listdir(inputDir):

    layercount = os.path.join(inputDir, i)
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(layercount, "raster")

    fileOut = outputDir + "\\" + i

    processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", \
    raster_layer, \
    "EPSG:4326", \
    "EPSG:27700", \
    10, \
    0, \
    None, \
    5, \
    fileOut)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import *


raster_filepath = "R:\\LAI_Biom_Maps\\kriging_Gladys\\in"

outputDir = "R:\\LAI_Biom_Maps\\kriging_Gladys\\out"

for i in os.listdir(raster_filepath):

    layercount = os.path.join(raster_filepath, i)
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(layercount, 'raster')

    fileOut = outputDir + "\\" + i

    processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", \
    raster_layer, \
    "EPSG:4326", \
    "EPSG:27700", \
    "0", \
    10, \
    0, \
    None, \
    None, \
    5, \
    0, \
    75, \
    6, \
    1, \
    False, \
    0, \
    False, \
    "", \
    fileOut)
```

Comment: What happened ? Is that because you were missing arguments in the processing alg ?

Comment: Yes. Then I've found all the arguments needed to make everything working in a book.

Comment: @ilFonta - Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Comment: Ohps. I really apologize for this. Thank you for the advice! Cheers